# Is it possible to add a collider to an alembic animation in C4D?

Tags: animation, cinema4d

i'm new to C4D and i'm trying to have an animation i made in blender interact with a soft body object in C4D. But when i create a collider and start the animation, nothing happens, the animation just goes through the object. Anybody has experience with that kinda stuff ? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use Houdini?

Comment: No, just a regular soft-body simulation inside C4D.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your animation is too fast or the scale is off a bit.

Try to increase the "steps per frame" under the project settings>Dynamics>Expert tab. That should allow for more accurate dynamics calculations. This will also lower the viewer fps as it requires more compute cycles.

[image: Steps Per Frame]